# How to access Vue component data and router from external javascript functions?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vue-router

I am new to Vue. I am trying to build a sort of middleware where I can check for all the status codes and handle it the wait I want.

I want to use this function everywhere I send a request to the backend. To prevent code duplication, im using a middleware function.

the function:

```
module.exports.serverErrorMiddleware = async (res)=>{  
   const status = res.status;
   if(status == 500) return router.push('/error') //problem 1
   if(status == 404) return router.push('/notfound')
   if(status == 302) return router.push('/login')
   if(status == 403 && !(res.error.isrefTokenError)) return router.push('/unauthorized')
   if(status == 400) this.error = res.error.message  // problem 2

   if(status == 401){
   if(!localStorage.getItem('refresh_token')) return router.push('/login')
     try{
        const response = 
        await axios({
            method : 'get',
            url    : 'http://localhost:5000/api/auth/newtoken'
        })
            localStorage.setItem('access_token' , response.auth.accessToken);
    }catch(err){
        if(err.response.status == 403 && err.response.error.isrefTokenError) return router.push('/login');
        router.push('/error')
    }
}
}
```

problem 1 : I want to push a new route into the `router` for redirects but dont know how to access the `router`

problem 2 : I want to change the `data` in the Vue component from this function. I want to show the error to the user according to the error I receive from the server. So I want to access the `error` property in `data` of the component this function is called from.

I call this function in the `catch` of `axios` request

```
 async submitForm(event){
        event.preventDefault()

        try{
             const response = await axios({
                method : 'post',
                url : 'http://localhost:5000/api/auth/register',
                data : {
                    username : this.formData.username,
                    password : this.formData.password
                }
             })
             console.log(response)
        }catch(err){
            serverErrorMiddleware(err.response)
        }
    }
```

Comment: What you try to do is usually done in Axios interceptors and router beforeEnter hooks. 1. Import a variable from a place where you create router instance. A "middleware" doesn't smell good. Random redirects will cause really bad UX. A decision to redirect is usually made at higher level, e.g. when you load data in beforeRouteEnter hook, you may want to redirect if it failed. 2. It's unclear what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks. I will have a look at your suggestion. I have edited the question to make problem 2 more clear.